# When using BeautifulSoup, html has needed data in a different index number in some search results

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, findall

I am having an issue with a website's format causing certain information within a container to have different index numbers from one search result to the next.

I am scraping pieces of data from search results. The location/Index Numbers are different in a few cases.

Basically, the exact text I need scraped from the html below is "7XB21".

```html
<dl class="last">
    ::before
    <dt>Part Code:</dt>
    <dd>
        "7XB21"
        <span class="separator">,</span>
    < /dd>
    <dt>Weight:</dt>
    <dd>97</dd>
</dl>
```

This is easy to do the with Python code below, as it gets me the result I need which is "7XB21"

```css
modelcode_container = container.find_all("dd")
        modelcode = (modelcode_container[5].text)
```

HOWEVER!
Some of the HTML code scraped, while being structured the same, lacks some information which the above example shows. Here is an example of the troublesome HTML:

```html
<dl class="last">
    <dt>Stock id:</dt>
    <dd>c12
        <span class="separator">,</span>
    </dd>
    <dt>Part Code:</dt>
    <dd>
        "8B727"
        <span class="separator">,</span>
    </dd>
    <dt>Weight:</dt>
    <dd>102</dd>
</dl>
```

Do you see the difference? I would need to specify a different index number to capture the proper data which is "8B727" in this case.

I am not sure how to go about setting that up, any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are certain that `<dt>Part Code:</dt>` occurs before that you could use [find_next_sibling()](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-next-siblings-and-find-next-sibling) to get the `dd` tag next to it.

```
soup.find('dt',text="Part Code:").find_next_sibling('dd')
```

Comment: That was it, he one thing I forgot to mention was that I do know for a fact that <dt>Part Code:</dt> will always occur immediately before.

Thank you very much for the help. This guarantees it will find the right information regardless of where it is in the index